# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData earlierDate:]

Tags: swift

After Swift 3.0 conversion from swift 2.2 im facing the below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData earlierDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x149aa2e70'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first guess, look for a `Data()` that should have been a `Date()`, or an `NSData()` that should have been an `NSDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `NSData` variable instead of `NSDate` object where the exception is being raised from in your code. There is no selector declared like `earlierDate` on `NSData`.

To find it where it is exactly, switch on exception breakpoint in Xcode on the left panel.

[image]